# Python Calculator Kinematics

Tags: python

Hey guys what I'm trying to do here is make a very basic kinematics variable solver, so I've got the basic equation vf = vi + at. Now what I'm trying to do is make it so if you don't know the variable, you input / which is the variable you solve for. But the problem is, when I try to enter the variable as / it gives me an error because I'm using integers. But if I remove the int() from each variable it wont let the equations work! I'm stuck, if anyone can give me some input it'd be greatly appreciated. It seems my image isn't uploading so heres a gyazo link for it https://gyazo.com/3325b42c51f839dc901cdefc1fe9b7fd

```
vf = input("What is the final velocity?")
if vf == "/":
 dontuse = "vf"
else:
    pass
vi = int(input("What is the intial velocity?"))
if vi == "/":
  dontuse = "vi"
else:
  pass
a = int(input("What is the acceleration?"))
if a == "/":
  dontuse = "a"
else:
  pass
t = int(input("What is the time?"))
if t == "/":
  dontuse = "t"
else:
  pass
def eq1():
 vf = vi + a*t
def eq2():
  vi = vf/(a*t)
def eq3():
  t = (vf - vi)/a
if dontuse == "vf":
  eq1()
```

Comment: could you paste the code so that i may look at it

Comment: i think i understand the problem if you could paste the code i might fix it

Comment: There you go, sorry about that. I included a gyazo link to it also.

Comment: do you have to use functions at the end??

Comment: I'm not sure. I could use anything you recommend. I'm just trying to make a program that spits out the missing variable. If you have a better idea please share.

Comment: ok so what happens if he gives value to all of the stuff

(i am just finishing the code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so the problem was that you were taking the input in the form of an Int but you asked the user to enter '/' which is a string.
In some versions, this doesn't give an error but here it does

secondly, you were calculating in the Int variable which is ineffective in multiplication and division so instead, I used float which has better accuracy.

```
dontuse=''

vf = input("What is the final velocity?")
if vf == "/":
 dontuse = "vf"
else:
    vf=float(vf)

vi = str(input("What is the floatial velocity?"))
if vi == "/":
  dontuse = "vi"
else:
  vi=float(vi)

a = str(input("What is the acceleration?"))
if a == "/":
  dontuse = "a"
else:
  a=float(a)

t = str(input("What is the time?"))
if t == "/":
  dontuse = "t"
else:
  t=float(t)


def eq1():
    vf = vi + a*t
    print("vf: "+str(vf))
def eq2():
    vi = vf/(a*t)
    print("vi: "+str(vi))
def eq3():
    t = (vf - vi)/a
    print("t: "+str(t))

def eq4():
    a = (vf - vi)/t
    print("a: "+str(a))



if dontuse == "vf":
    eq1()
elif dontuse=='vi':
    eq2()
elif dontuse=='a':
    eq4()
elif dontuse=='t':
    eq3()
else:
    print('All value known')
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: accept my answer it will come a long way ty in advance